# VS Setup Project - Launch condition for .Net Framework 3.5 or higher

Tags: c#, .net, installation, setup-project

I need to create a setup project for my application. I need to add launch condition to make sure user has .Net framework 3.5 or higher installed on his machine. Is there a way to do so?

I have tried creating the setup project in VS 2005, 2008 and 2010. I have also tried setting up the version in launch condition to be 3.5 and then opened the project file in notepad to set "Allow Later Versions" to true, without any success.

The setup still asks me to download .Net framework 3.5 when I have .Net framework 4.0 installed on my system.

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Thanks,
Manjeet

Comment: I am also having the same issue; we set the `AllowLaterVersions` property to True in the .vdproj file and when .NET4 only is installed the MSI prompts you to download 3.5

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't want to edit project file manually. "Allow Later versions" flag is for your application not for .net framework I think; isn't it?

If you do as per [this](http://blog.objectpattern.com/dot-net/changing-version-of-net-framework-dependency-for-setup-and-deployment-project-in-visual-studio-2008/) tutorial it should work fine. I've never seen your problem before. I think you must have done something wrong, other wise it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was also experiencing the same problem. I found that
- *Visual studio 2008* started to use `ToolsVersion` attribute to target the framework
- Framework 4.0 doesn't include framework 3.5

In my case, I installed 3.5 (along with 4.0) and the setup is working fine now.